# Teradata Week Calculation

Tags: sql, teradata, week-number

I have a query in teradata where i am trying to get the week number from a specific date in the format yyyymmdd (20160201). We have a calendar table (not the teradata one because we count weeks slightly differently) which allows you to join the date and export the results

When i run the query with static dates so for the example below runs fine

```
FROM table_main AL1
 JOIN cal_table cal
  ON  AL1.run_date = cal.cal_dateyyyymmdd
WHERE AL1.run_date >= 20160201
AND AL1.run_date < 20160220
```

When i try to generalize the statement to the previous week

```
FROM table_main AL1
 JOIN cal_table cal
  ON  AL1.run_date = cal.cal_dateyyyymmdd
WHERE AL1.run_date >= CAST(CAST(((DATE-DAYOFWEEK(DATE)-5) (FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD')) AS CHAR(8)) AS INT)
AND AL1.run_date < CAST(CAST(((DATE-DAYOFWEEK(DATE)+ 1) (FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD')) AS CHAR(8)) AS INT)
```

I get the error

> SELECT Failed. 3706:  Syntax error: expected something between ')' and '-'.

Has anyone ever seen this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DAYOFWEEK` is not an existing Teradata function, it's ODBC syntax, which is sometimes (apparantely not in your case) automatically translated by the ODBC-driver to valid Teradata SQL. It will work when you use the correct syntax `{fn DAYOFWEEK(DATE_)}`, but imho you should always avoid those ODBC functions (check *Disable Parsing* in the ODBC options), because it will fail when you submit the same query using JDBC/.NET/CLI.

And your calculation is overly complicated, try to avoid expensive typecasts date/string:

```
WHERE AL1.run_date >= CAST(NEXT_DAY(DATE-13, 'mon') AS INT) + 19000000
AND AL1.run_date < CAST(NEXT_DAY(DATE-7, 'sun') AS INT) + 19000000

NEXT_DAY(..., 'mon') -- find the next monday
CAST(... AS INT) -- returns YYMMDD
... + 19000000 -- to match your date key
```

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth. this is what i was looking for. I also found that i can remove the table completely and use `week(cast((run_date -  19000000 ) AS DATE)) as week_num` which seems to work

Comment: @JohnSmith: `week` is another ODBC function and I doubt it's always returning the correct number. If you need ISO weeks `WEEKNUMBER_OF_YEAR` might be what you want, there's an `ISO` option.

Answer (score 0):

you can't put the (**AS**) in the (**where clause**)
It's accepted only in the query columns.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick response. Im not sure i follow. If i use`CAST(CAST(((DATE-DAYOFWEEK(DATE)-5) (FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD')) AS CHAR(8)) AS INT)` and don't join on to the other table on it, it works fine. Is it just not allowed when you want to join another table?

Comment: use it like this:

FROM table_main AL1
 JOIN cal_table cal
  ON  AL1.run_date = cal.cal_dateyyyymmdd
WHERE AL1.run_date >= CAST(CAST(((DATE-DAYOFWEEK(DATE)-5) (FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD')) AS CHAR(8)) )
AND AL1.run_date < CAST(CAST(((DATE-DAYOFWEEK(DATE)+ 1) (FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD')) AS CHAR(8))  INT)

Comment: Hi @Mohamed, Could you explain to me what you changed as it looks identical to the problem statement in my second chunk of code

Comment: sorry @JohnSmith i missed understanding, it's my first time to see (CAST) statement. i'll delete my answer.